# Set Currency format in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Model in C#

```
    public class Model
    {
        public int CurrencyId{ get; set; }
        public decimal? ValueMoney{ get; set; }
    }
```

and from Database I receive the  `List<Model>`

I want to write the ValueMoneys in Excel Worksheet in Currency format and depending on CurrencyId it has to be US dollar $ or Brazilian Real R$.

I am using using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

My code look like this:

```
var data = GetValues().ToList();
Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1];

for (int i = 1; i < data.count; i++){
     xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = data[i].ValueMoney!= null ? data[i].CurrencyId == 2 ? data[i].ValueMoney.Value.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("pt-BR")) : data[i].ValueMoney.Value.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US")) : "";       
    ((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1]).Style = "Currency" ;
}
```

The problem is that in Excel it shows me the warning that it is a string and ask to change to number format.

I was trying to use

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = data[i].ValueMoney
((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1]).NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
```

but it always shows R$  since I am in Brazil.
Thank you for help in advance.

[UPDATE]
It works

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = data[i].ValueMoney;
((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1]).NumberFormat = data[i].CurrencyId == 2 ? "$ #,##0.00" : "[$$-409] #,##0.00";
```

Comment: To set the value you need to set the `Value` property of the cell, and the NumberFormat should also go to the same cell (you use `[i, 1]` and then `[l, 9]`). So I think it should be `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = data[i].ValueMoney` and `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"`.

Comment: The second way did not work because the excel get the culture info from your system operation. 
Why you just create a new column before the column of value in the excel with the text showing  US dollar $ or R$? could be a text and solve your problem.

Comment: I made mistake writing here the code - I do in both places  [i, 1]. I only show a piece of my code, and adding the new column to show currency is not good for me

Comment: in the number format replace `$` with `[$$-409]` or `[$$-en-US]`

Comment: @Slai it looks like your idea is good :) More accurently
((Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1]).NumberFormat = data[i].CurrencyId == 2 ? "$ #,##0.00" : "[$$-409] #,##0.00";

Comment: If you don't use Slai's method of providing the locale, you need to put the $ sign in quotes, because it's the placeholder for the system's currency. So you could use `"\"$\" #,##0.00"`.

Comment: check the 2 Format Cells dialog screenshots here https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/#currency-symbols

Comment: @Slai where can I find this codes? Would be nice to have the same for Brazilian currency, since someone who will use my code will get wrong currency while being in other country

Comment: I think backslash also can be used to escape symbols `@"\$ #,0.00"`

Comment: But still I can't get the code for Brazil R$, the Excel does't show me, because I am here ( I think)

Comment: @Slai @ckuri  `"\"$\" #,##0.00"` and `@"\$ #,0.00"` do not work, I always receive R$ instead of $. So the best solution is  `[$$-en-US]` Thank You for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locale code for US dollar $ is `[$$-en-US]`, and for Brazilian Real R$ is `[$R$-pt-BR]`. For example :

```
.NumberFormat = "[$$-en-US] #,##0.00";
```

The locale codes can be found by setting the Symbol in the Currency section of the Excel Format Cells dialog, and then checking the corresponding number format in the Custom section of the same dialog.